# Async map for Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework

`Node.js` has one thing like this [async modules](https://github.com/caolan/async).
Does anyone know - how to organize something like this :

```
async.map(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.stat, function(err, results){
      // results is now an array of stats for each file
});
```

Currently I'm using a Play Framework/Scala

Comment: What would be the type of `fs.stat` in this case?

Comment: I think using `Future` with `Action.async` could be solution here. I am not sure in what context you want to use this.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek function for each values

Comment: @Maria *What* function? `A => Future[B]`? Or `A => B`? The second one doesn't really make much sense in this context, but if you already have async processing for every element, you can simply do `Future.sequence(files.map(fn)).map(results => ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Provided you find the equivalent of `fs.stat` (I don't think it is the purpose of your question), you can use [Parallel Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html). You would get something like this:

```
Vector("file1","file2","file3").par.map(f => function(fs.stat(f)))
```